# Effects of 2 crontabs

Tags: cron

By accident made 2 different crontabs:

First  with sudo crontab -e

Second with crontab -e

Just asking what happens (because did not find an explanation):

1) If they are different, are both being executed?

2) If both are identical, which one is executed? Or prone to a 'collision'?

Comment: sudo just gives you admin privileges, it does not change the command. It is possible you just changed the one you created earlier with sudo.

Comment: there's a change, sudo will create the crontab for the root user which is different than the user crontab

Comment: oh I never knew you could create multiple crontabs. Half knowledge is indeed dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo crontab -e` will create cron tasks for the root account, and these tasks will be executed as root. Running `crontab -e` without sudo will create cron tasks for your user, and the tasks will be executed as that user.

Comment: I think you're right, but I also think that you should add your conclusion, which I guess is: yes it runs twice the same command

Comment: Is any priority applicable between the 2 cronsets? 'Root' before 'user'? Or 'first come, first served'?

Answer (score 0):

Each user can have his own `crontab`. The first one will be executed from `root`, as you ran it with `sudo`, and the second one from your own user.